# How send IOS push notifications to group of people out of all?

Tags: ios, push-notification

***I am getting one frequent question on push notification.***

Actually i haven't worked on push notifications till now, But i know how to implement. i have learned form blogs and videos.

But i am getting frequent question in interviews as below.

*lets imagine 
10 users register for push notifications in app.*

**Q   : - How can we send a push notification to the 3 only people out of 10 ?**

**ANS** : I have given answer like we will send device token to register with the remote notification. Form backend we will filter users or device tokens with calling server api call who wants that service. We  will get set of people who send api  call for that particular service.

***But the they are not at all satisfying with the answer.***

**- Is there any way to send push notifications to some people in group ?
is it possible to validate form device itself ?**

***Which is the best way to achieve this case ?***

Comment: This is backend part. You should store each device tokens against user in database. While sending push notification, you must decide to which users you wanna send and then get device tokens from those users, so you will be able to send push notifications to selected group of people.

Comment: In my case, my service saved user's device token in a database. When users open the application, they send a new device token to my backend system. And I developed the function that I can select the notification receiver on the backend. Then I can search conditionally, for example the address, age range, hobby and so on. Of course users have to set the information on the application. If you don't want to backend system, you should use UILocalNotification. So you can be ready for the trigger in the application.